# creating sub-array form a large array based on the first element of the large array

Tags: python, list

I have an array,

```
list =  [['a', '2', '7'], ['b', '2', '9'],['a', '1', '4'],['c', '6', '1'],['b', '9', '9'],['a', '3', '2'],['c', '1', '5'],['b', '3', '7']]
```

I can write:

```
aList =  [[row [1], row [2]] for row in list if row [0] == "a"] 
bList =  [[row [1], row [2]] for row in list if row [0] == "b"]
cList =  [[row [1], row [2]] for row in list if row [0] == "c"]
```

to make a sub-array of second and third elements that has a specific first element i.e. ‘a’ , ‘b’ or  ‘c’. 
But I want to know what is the way to write one code that will do the work for all the first element.

Comment: Can you add an example of your expected output? I'm not sure I understand what you want.

Comment: That's a list not an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a dictionary with the first item as key and rest of the items as values. [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) will make this task a little easier for you, you can do this using a plain `dict` as well:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> lst = [['a', '2', '7'], ['b', '2', '9'],['a', '1', '4'],['c', '6', '1'],['b', '9', '9'],['a', '3', '2'],['c', '1', '5'],['b', '3', '7']]
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for x in lst:
        d[x[0]].append(x[1:])
        #For plain dict this is going to be:
        #d.setdefault(x[0], []).append(x[1:]) 

>>> d['a']
[['2', '7'], ['1', '4'], ['3', '2']]
>>> d['b']
[['2', '9'], ['9', '9'], ['3', '7']]
>>> d['c']
[['6', '1'], ['1', '5']]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import operator

L = [['a', '2', '7'], ['b', '2', '9'],['a', '1', '4'],['c', '6', '1'],['b', '9', '9'],['a', '3', '2'],['c', '1', '5'],['b', '3', '7']]

lists = {'a':[], 'b':[], 'c':[]}
g = operator.itemgetter(1,2)
for t in L:
    lists[t[0]].append(g(t))

print('aList:', lists['a'])
print('bList:', lists['b'])
print('cList:', lists['c'])
```

Output:

```
aList: [('2', '7'), ('1', '4'), ('3', '2')]
bList: [('2', '9'), ('9', '9'), ('3', '7')]
cList: [('6', '1'), ('1', '5')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary can do this work for you.

```
dict_list = {}
for row in list:
    dict_list.setdefault(row[0],[])
    dict_list[row[0]].append(row[1:])
```

`setdefault` will set the value as empty list `[]` if the key doesn't exist.
Output:

```
>>>dict_list
{'a': [['2', '7'], ['1', '4'], ['3', '2']], 
'c': [['6', '1'], ['1', '5']], 
'b': [['2', '9'], ['9', '9'], ['3', '7']]}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am sure this is a stupid question, but when i tried the code with my original list, i got the following error massage: "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'"... what should i do?